# Fatal PHP error upon installation

Tags: craft3, php, error, install, yii

I attempted to install the newest version of Craft and received this error in my logs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\craft-cms\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php on line 1292
```

I'm unsure of the cause of this error, but the the lines around 1292 in the `command.php` file seem to be an exception handler for database transactions.

I don't achieve a different result after lengthening the execution time. I've tried setting very lenient firewalls and administrator rights. I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling all of the files. I still receive the same error every time.

Any ideas to fix this issue? I haven't found another post about this issue online, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to install Craft via command line? Or via the browser?

Comment: The PHP execution the browser uses is a different one than the PHP executable the console uses and therefore they have different php.ini files.  Make sure you're editing the correct one when bumping the `max_execution_time` setting.

Comment: I installed via the command line.
Thank you both for your responses. I was able to fix the issue by maximizing the execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue- I was able to fix the issue by setting the execution time as infinite and then waiting for an hour.